# How to specify the same token on jupyter-notebook server?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I always have to restart a jupyter-notebook server on reboot or failure and as expected it starts with a different token, but this ruins the link for my existing users. Is there a way to specify the same token everytime?

If not, what is the alternative?

Comment: I think using a password can prevent you from it: `jupyter notebook password`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RE: The question, "Is there a way to specify the same token everytime?"

Start jupyter notebook as you normally do. That information is not in the question. So my answer and example is based on:

1. Activate a conda environment
2. Use a port number so users can add a link in their browser.
3. Start jupyter notebook
4. Copy the token
5. Use the command line to start jupyter notebook.

Example:

```
jupyter notebook --port=9000 --NotebookApp.token='6c4bfd9ffd59618566557195d0f0a733f246545b8b118ca7'
```

Answer (score 1):

From here:

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html

> As of notebook 5.3, the first time you log-in using a token, the
> notebook server should give you the opportunity to setup a password
> from the user interface.
>
> You will be presented with a form asking for the current *token*, as
> well as your *new* *password* ; enter both and click on Login and
> setup new password.
>
> Next time you need to log in you’ll be able to use the new password
> instead of the login token, otherwise follow the procedure to set a
> password from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Ohk, so what you can do is, disable the token and password for the jupyter notbook by passing these arguments  `--NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''`

Comment: You should mention the security implications of doing this if you are to suggest it.